# Connect 2 Win 7 PCs via RS-232 DB9 serial cable

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, serial-port, null-modem

Is it possible to connect 2 windows 7 PCs directly(Direct cable connection) via RS-232 DB9 serial cable?

I tried looping data back to the same PC by shorting pins 2 and 3 with a jumper and used Hyperterminal and PuTTY, and enter characters in the console appeared as expected. But when 2 PCs are connected it fails to display the enter text from other PC.

Has anyone used this rs-232 serial cable on windows 7/8 platform or do I need to use USB to RS-232 for windows 7/8 as modern motherboards do not have serial ports.

[Serial cable used and PC ports](http://www.imagesup.net/pm-1013783811214.png%5D%5BIMG%5Dhttp://www.imagesup.net/dm-1013783811214.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need a [null-modem cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem) for such a connection.

However, if you just connect two PCs by such a cable, per default no service is listening on the RS232c port to answer login attempts. You could install a [slip driver](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/dial-up-slip-connection-in-windows-7/24d3913a-46f1-4673-a358-1e80366675df) and establish an IP connection via RS232. This would allow you to use network tools like [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) or [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com).

There is also a [Telnet Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754837%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) available for `Windows 7`. This could answer [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) (= telnet client), provided the IP connection is working.

Other non-RS232c options would be an [USB-USB bridge cable](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Connecting-Two-PCs-Using-a-USB-USB-Cable/248) or a crossed Lan (local area network) cable.

Comment: There is slight confusion here: you don't need IP connection if using Putty with "serial" mode ;)

Comment: I used PuTTY and HyperTerminal for only for testing the "Null modem cable" and PC port as in the link "Serial cable used and PC ports". I would be using Serial Port Communication(C++)through Windows API. But in Windows 7 the connection is not being established.

Comment: Yes, you can use two terminal programs like putty "back-to-back" to check the connectivity. But to do something more useful, you are going to need some service of program which listens on the RS232c port.